# Iterate through list of strings and replace certain characters

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a list of string in python.

```
header_row = ['column 1', 'column 2', 'column 3']
```

I want to replace the empty space with underscore. The converted list will look like this;

```
converted_header_row = ['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
```

The conversion can be done individually with the line below;

```
mystring.replace(" ", "_")
```

How do I iterate this replacement operation through all the strings in the list? I welcome any other method to do the conversion.

I am using python v3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a list comprehension:

```
header_row = [mystring.replace(" ", "_") for mystring in header_row]
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested to work!